# Different aggregate functions depending on datatype

Tags: database, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a T-SQL script that returns all columns in a table, along with datatype and max value `MAX(DATALENGTH))` fetching it from `sys.columns` and `sys.types`.

However the max value will always be 4 for ints, since ints uses 4 bytes. In this case I'd rather have the highest numeric value of the column.

I figured I might change my query to use `DataLength` for string-based columns, and a `MAX()` for number based columns, however I run into some problems before I even get there:

#### Minified example code

```
DECLARE @A bit = 1
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN MAX(DATALENGTH(@A)) ELSE MAX(@A) END
```

I would expect to receive the number 1 given that `1=1`  is true.
Instead I get an error

> Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

I understand that you can't run `MAX(@A)` on a bit, but that's not what I'm trying to do. My goal is to run different aggregate functions depending on the datatype.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Aside: `CASE` does not reliably provide short circuit evaluation. See [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order), [FREETEXT() does not honor order of evaluation in CASE statements](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/780132/) and [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to run different aggregate functions depending on the datatype.

This will fail because you will get invalid cast errors or will get implicit conversions to the highest precedence data type

Your use of `bit` is irrelevant here

[smalldatetime has the highest precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) so this code gives odd results when mixing datatypes

```
DECLARE @foo table (
 intval int,
 floatval float,
 datetimeval smalldatetime)

 INSERT @foo VALUES
 (1, 1.567E2, '2017-07-31'),
 (2, 2.0, '2017-08-01');

 DECLARE @Switch int;
 SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN @Switch=1 THEN MAX(intval)
            WHEN @Switch=2 THEN MAX(floatval)
            ELSE MAX(datetimeval) 
        END
FROM 
    @foo

 SET @Switch = 1
 1900-01-03 00:00:00

 SET @Switch = 2
 1900-06-06 16:48:00

 SET @Switch = 3
 2017-08-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: What problem? All we have if your chosen solution which to an unknown problem

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are missing a cast :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN MAX(DATALENGTH(@A)) ELSE MAX(CAST(@A as bigint)) END
```